# ASP.NET Same Code with different using statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I'm working on an insurance project and the policy details page needs to look the same for every year, however there is some background logic that generates the data a little differently for each year. The code I am writing for each year is 100% identical, I just need to import the policy logic for the corresponding year and that is the only difference.

Would there a way to dynamically generate the using statements based on some year value I could pass in when I generate the control? Or somehow create a super class that would contain all the code and then I could just subclass out the using statements?

To give an example:

```
using PolicyYear.Y13;

namespace Controls.Policy.Y13.UserControl
{
    public partial class PolicyDetail : UserControlYearBase
....
}
```

The UserControlYearBase is pulled in from the PolicyYear.Y13 class, and there would be the exact same control in files for PolicyYear.Y14, .Y15, etc. I want to be able to dynamically generate the Y## for whatever the selected year is.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use an interface.

Comment: Any time you're writing multiple instances of code that is 100% identical you're probably doing something wrong.  Check the DRY principle - "Don't Repeat Yourself".  Imagine that something in that code has to change, and you've got it 25 years (or 25 instances) that exist.  Do you really want to make that change or update 25 times?

Comment: "Favor composition over inheritance" -> You should extract the logic part into its own class that is than somehow injected into the user control that will exist only once

Comment: You can also look at [T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to dynamically generate your files.